# Variable dimension array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, signal-processing

I'm trying to save some data into python. The data is composed for a series of text delimited files. The problem is that the files have different len() and I do not know the len() before reading. 
I was trying to know if it possible to save the files in a 2D array with something like this:

```
s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 ..
s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 ..
.. s2 s3 .. s5 ..
.. .. s3    s5 ..
            s5 ..
```

In this case if I want to access all the values from signal 1 I'll make something like this:
    s[:,0]

I was also thinking in implementing this in a for loop.
read_data is a function that returns an array containing the processed file and files a list containing all the files paths

```
 for i in range(len(files)):
     all_files[:,i] = read_data(files[i])
```

However, since I do not initiate all_files prior this will not work. In the meantime, if I want to initiate all_files prior the reading I'll struggling to know what "vertical" dimensions will I use, because the "horizontal" should be easier: len(files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would collect the file data in a list - a list of lists - and then worry about repackaging it as an array after.  Appending to a list is cheap.

e.g.

```
all_files = []
for i in range(len(files)):
    all_files.append(read_data(files[i]))
```

Now you can get information like the number of files, `N=len(all_files)`, and the maximum length, `M=max(len(f) for f in all_files)`.

```
all_data = np.zeros((N,M)), dtype=???)
for i in range(N):
    all_data[i,:] = pad_function(all_files[i])
```

where `pad_function` pads the data from one file to fit the maximum size.

An alternative is to figure out where in all_data you want to put the data, and create an index vector `j = [0,1,3,5,...]`:

```
all_data[i,j] = all_files[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a crude way of doing it, but you can get the maximum of the
length of all the files using the following snippet. You can use that for the size of vertical dimension.

```
max_len = 0
for i in len(files):
    if len(files[i]) > max_len:
        max_len = len(files[i])
```

Comment: or `max_len = max(len(f) for f in files)`